# How to grant remote access to MySQL for a whole subnet?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I can easily grant access to one IP using this code:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:    
mysql> use mysql    
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.1.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';     
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But i need to allow the whole subnet 192.168.1.* to access the database remotely.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

EDIT: Consider looking at and upvoting [Malvineous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742963/how-to-grant-remote-access-to-mysql-for-a-whole-subnet/38389851#38389851)'s answer on this page. Netmasks are a much more elegant solution.

---

Simply use a percent sign as a wildcard in the IP address.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example, `user_name@'%.example.com'` applies to `user_name` for any host in the `example.com` domain, and `user_name@'192.168.1.%'` applies to `user_name` for any host in the `192.168.1` class C subnet.

Comment: I just did it like this, but, say, what makes it not apply to: user_name@'192.168.1.my-hacked-rnds.killing.mysql.com'???? i'll now walk on, since this being MySQL I sense I don't want to know the answer.

Comment: +Florian, I figure it beats simply using '%' as it does add a layer of security that must be overcome, but I think you do make a good point about its weakness. I certainly supplement this configuration by other means, such as locking the database server in a separate subnet that I can control access to via a firewall to negate your concerns, among other things.

Comment: Examples like '192.168.1.my-hacked-rnds.killing.mysql.com'' are specifically addressed in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html : _To foil such attempts, MySQL disallows matching on host names that start with digits and a dot.  ... An IP wildcard value can match only IP addresses, not host names._

Answer (score 158):

It [looks like you can also use a netmask](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html), e.g.

```
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY ...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only technical correct one. Supported since at least 5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html

Comment: Do not try to use CIDR notation like "172.16.0.0/16", this does not work. Always use the full netmask.

Comment: It appears you have to use the first IP address in the range; Using for example 192.168.0.34/255.255.255.0 will fail!

Comment: @SanderBackus: `192.160.0.34/255.255.255.0` is the same as `192.168.0.34/24` which doesn't really make sense (`/24` means the last number can be from 0 to 255, ignoring your value of 34).  Does it work if you use a valid mask for the IP, like `192.168.0.34/255.255.255.252`?

Comment: @Malvineous That was my point. If you use 192.160.0.34/255.255.255.0 mysql does not allow 192.160.0.34. I meant to allow full /24 (yes I used full netmask, as documented), but apparently If you have to use 192.160.0.0/255.255.255.0 to allow full range.

Comment: @SanderBackus: Right sorry, I thought you were trying to allow a /25 or smaller by using `.34`.

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh From the link in the answer "Netmask notation cannot be used for IPv6 addresses."

Comment: Netmasks are also supported in MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#host-name-component

Answer (score 34):

You would just use '%' as your wildcard like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';
```

Answer (score 17):

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';
```

The wildcard character is a "%" instead of an "*"

Answer (score 9):

Just a note of a peculiarity I faced:
Consider:

```
db server:  192.168.0.101
web server: 192.168.0.102
```

If you have a user defined in mysql.user as `'user'@'192.168.0.102'` with password1 and another `'user'@'192.168.0.%'` with password2,

then,

if you try to connect to the db server from the web server as 'user' with password2,

it will result in an 'Access denied' error because the single IP  `'user'@'192.168.0.102'` authentication is used over the wildcard `'user'@'192.168.0.%'` authentication.

Comment: I am not sure this is an answer to the question. If it doesn't provide a direct answer to the original question it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Kmeixner , you expect him to write so much in a comment? Apply some common sense and stop being a robot. This community is for helping the developers not to make their life difficult.

Comment: Thanks for this invaluable tip.

Answer (score 4):

Motivated by @Malvineaus answer I tried it myself and noticed that it didn't work for me.

You can specify subnet masks with '192.168.1.%' or '192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0' but the subnet must always be on complete octets. see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#host-name-component. As result the functionality between one way of specification and the other is the same.

For example '192.168.1.0/255.255.255.128' will not work as it is not on a complete octet boundary.

Answer (score 3):

[MySQL 8.0.23 onwards](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) now support CIDR notation also.

So, basically:

```sql
-- CIDR Notation
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'192.168.1.0/24' IDENTIFIED BY ...

-- Netmask Notation
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

after you connect server and you want to connect on your host, you should do the steps below:

1. write **mysql** to open mysql
2. write **`GRANT ALL ON . to root@'write_your_ip_addres' IDENTIFIED BY 'write_password_to_connect'`**;
3. press control and X to quit from mysql
4. write **`nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`**
5. write # before **bind-address = 127.0.0.1** in my.cnf folder
6. **#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1**
7. save my.cnf folder with control + X
8. write **`service mysql restart`**
9. you could connect via navicat on your host