# Grant remote access to mysql for an ipv6 subnet

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

This is a similar question to [How to grant remote access to MySQL for a whole subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742963/how-to-grant-remote-access-to-mysql-for-a-whole-subnet?rq=1), but with an IPv6 subnet. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html, the host_ip/netmask format is not allowed for IPv6. So how do I allow connections from my IPv6 subnet in ?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem, we are switching our networks over to IPv6 and immediately had login issues with applications that used to be on an IPv4 network.

This stackoverflow answer to the same question using IPv4 applies to IPv6.

[How to grant remote access to MySQL for a whole subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742963/how-to-grant-remote-access-to-mysql-for-a-whole-subnet)

For a user I just created and tested, I did the following:

`CREATE USER 'newuser'@'2001:DB8:100:feed::%' INDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';`

Then I granted that user access to the database in question:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON crowd.* to 'crowduser'@'2603:3026:100:13e1:%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I used mysql client from the server on the  2001:DB8:100:feed::/64 subnet to then access the database.

Comment: There is no CIDR (introduced in 1993) support in mysql/mariadb. Wildcards are a poor replacement for this basic functionality.