# Access denied to remote user when doing LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I'm running mariadb-server v10.2.33-1 on two openwrt-qemu systems. I want a remote user to achieve LOCK TABLE on a particular table.

In the local mysql server, I have created a remote user and granted LOCK TABLES privilege using the following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT SELECT ON `qkd`.`RawKeyStatus` TO 'root'@'192.168.%';
GRANT LOCK TABLES ON `qkd`.* TO 'root'@'192.168.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Upon running `SHOW GRANTS` in the remote user system, I can notice the `LOCK TABLES` privilege has been assigned to `'root'@'192.168.%'`. The remote user also has `SELECT` privilege on the table `qkd.RawKeyStatus`.

However `LOCK TABLE qkd.RawKeyStatus READ;` command in the remote system fails with the error:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.%' to database 'qkd'
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Run **SHOW PROCESSLIST;** nd see from which System the remote user is login and change the **GRANT** if it not **192.168,%**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
| Id   | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                    | Info             | Progress |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
|    1 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    2 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    3 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    4 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    5 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 3357 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | init                     | show processlist |    0.000 |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
The issue was related to the wildcard 192.168.%. In order to give GRANT to all users of the subnet 192.168.A.B a correct wildcard would be 192.168.%.%

A more safer option is to use a subnet mask:

```
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY ...
```

Now `LOCK TABLE qkd.RawKeyStatus READ;` command runs perfectly with the output
**`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)`**

Reference: [How to grant remote access to MySQL for a whole subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11742963/8105718)

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to pass the –-single-transaction option to mysqldump:

for example:

```
$ mysqldump --single-transaction -u user -p DBNAME > backup.sql
```

ref: https://michaelrigart.be/mysqldump-1044-access-denied-using-lock-tables/